# Multivariate normal with multivariate normal mean

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, marginal-distribution

A random vector $\boldsymbol x$ is distributed as a multivariate normal
$$
\boldsymbol x \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol m, \Sigma)
$$
and the mean vector $\boldsymbol m$ itself is a multivariate normal
$$
\boldsymbol m \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\mu, \Delta)
$$

Is there a simple way to calculate the marginal probability density
$$
P(\boldsymbol x) = \int P(\boldsymbol x | \boldsymbol m) \; P(\boldsymbol m) \; \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol m
$$
without calculating the integrals explicitly?

It should come out that $\boldsymbol x$ is distributed as
$$
\boldsymbol x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma + \Delta)
$$
but I'm having difficulties to prove it.

Comment: Are $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$ known? Further, is this self-study or homework?

Comment: Both covariance matrices are known. This is self-study, I would like to understand how to do the marginalisation, as I know the result (just edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

> Rewrite $\boldsymbol x$ as $ (\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol m) + \boldsymbol m$.

**Hint 2:**

> Consider the algebraic properties of the expectations and covariances of independent multivariate Normals.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I thought there was an easy way out of this, and it helped me solve my actual problem that lead to this question.